# Unusual legend using size mapping and density2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a scatterplot in ggplot2 with a size mapping to a third variable and density2d contours. It seems as if the legend is being confused by the inclusion of density2d contours.

For example, the following code works:

```
library('ggplot2')
set.seed(1)
x=rnorm(100); y=rnorm(100,sd=10); z=seq(1,10,length.out=100)
dd=data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y,size=z))+geom_point()
```

[image: plot looks normal]

But now, note the legend behaves unusually when I add in a call to `stat_density2d()`. In particular, the plot legend shows blue blocks instead of black circles:

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y,size=z))+geom_point()+stat_density2d()
```

[image: plot legend shows blue blocks instead of black circles]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `size=` is one of the aesthetics you can set for the `stat_density2d()` and in this case it is set in `ggplot()` call, legend is made for both - lines and points (points are hided under lines in legend as `geom_point()` is called before `stat_density2d()`). To remove blue lines from legend, you can set manually `size=0.5` (or some other value) inside the `stat_density2d()` and then legend will be correct.

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y,size=z))+geom_point()+stat_density2d(size=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I'm not sure if this is helpful, but interchanging the order shows both legends (basically the filled circles were hiding behind the rectangles): `ggplot(dd,aes(x,y,size=z))+stat_density2d()+geom_point()`

Comment: @Arun yes, you are right - both legends are plotted (just hidden). Solution shows how to get rid of line widths in legend (as they are not meaningful in this case)

Comment: @DidzisElferts, yes I figured that once I saw your plot.